# cron output to a daemon process

Tags: shell, scripting, io, cron, daemon

I would like to know if I could make `cron.d` execute a cron command so that whatever comes on stdout or stderr is redirected to a daemon process running on the same machine waiting for an input. In this case, it would be the output at stdout or `stderr`.

Example:

```
* * * * * root /path/to/the/script.sh 2>&1 | <daemon process>
```

Comment: How is the daemon waiting for input? TCP/IPC socket? If so, you might look at netcat for piping data from stdin/stderr to some socket somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
* * * * * /path/to/the/script.sh 2>&1 | /path/to/the/daemon
```

?

I make the assumption that daemon read on `STDIN` (it's not mentioned in your post)

Comment: If it's a daemon, I don't think this will be the case

Comment: So OP should explain how the daemon is taking input